# Cache in python

Tags: python

Recently, I tried some code about cache. I have 2 codes, 1st with using dictionary. second with using cache library. I dont understand why the time running is so different. I thought the second which used the cache library works the same as the first.

First:
     import time
        import datetime

```
class new():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}

    def get_candy_price(self, candy_id):
        # let's use a sleep to simulate the time your function spends trying to connect to
        # the web service, 5 seconds will be enough.
        time.sleep(5)
        if candy_id % 2 not in self.cache:
            if candy_id % 2 == 0:
                self.cache[candy_id % 2] = 1.5
            else:
                self.cache[candy_id % 2] = 1

        # let's pretend that the price returned by the web service is $1 for candies with a
        # odd candy_id and $1,5 for candies with a even candy_id

        return (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%c"), self.cache[candy_id % 2])


# now, let's simulate 20 customers in your show.
# They are asking for candy with id 2 and candy with id 3...
for i in range(0,20):
    n = new()
    print(n.get_candy_price(2))
    print(n.get_candy_price(3))
```

Since everyone wants output:

Output:

```
('Thu Oct 25 16:14:27 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:14:32 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:14:37 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:14:42 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:14:47 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:14:52 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:14:57 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:02 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:07 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:12 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:17 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:22 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:27 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:32 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:37 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:42 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:47 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:52 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:15:57 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:02 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:07 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:12 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:17 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:22 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:27 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:32 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:37 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:42 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:47 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:52 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:16:57 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:02 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:07 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:12 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:17 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:22 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:27 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:32 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:37 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:17:42 2018', 1)

real    3m20.145s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Second:

```
import time
import datetime

from cachetools import cached, TTLCache  # 1 - let's import the "cached" decorator and the "TTLCache" object from cachetools
cache = TTLCache(maxsize=100, ttl=300)  # 2 - let's create the cache object.

@cached(cache)
def get_candy_price(candy_id):
    # let's use a sleep to simulate the time your function spends trying to connect to
    # the web service, 5 seconds will be enough.
    time.sleep(5)

    # let's pretend that the price returned by the web service is $1 for candies with a
    # odd candy_id and $1,5 for candies with a even candy_id

    price = 1.5 if candy_id % 2 == 0 else 1

    return (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%c"), price)


# now, let's simulate 20 customers in your show.
# They are asking for candy with id 2 and candy with id 3...
for i in range(0,20):
    print(get_candy_price(2))
    print(get_candy_price(3))
```

Output:

```
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:28 2018', 1.5)
('Thu Oct 25 16:32:33 2018', 1)

real    0m10.121s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Can anyone show me the example of codes in a more understanding way for cache in second? For example, is it possible to change it to something more easy to see how the library runs for cache such like in first? The difference is about 3minutes differ.

My goal:

Is to understand the cache in python and so I tried to implement two different ways; one with library and another without. So cache with library is actually the same as making our own dictionary? So does it mean by cache it means we make a dictionary which act as look-up table?

Comment: As you don’t actually say what the running time difference is between your two versions, it’s difficult to know what to say, and you risk close votes because you don’t include this information. Suggest you edit your results of running these into your question.

Comment: Edited, please check

Comment: Your first code only caches two possible keys since you always cache by the `candy_id`'s modulo of 2. Your second code caches all `candy_id` values as keys, on the other hand. They certainly won't behave the same, before the different implementations of caching come into considerations.

Comment: Haha you need to do the timing OUTSIDE the function that does the caching - as you can see, the returned time value is being cached and you appear to have frozen time.

Comment: Thank you! Now it became very fast but my goal is not to make it slower or anything but to verify whether are these two codes the same? I would like to understand the cache in python and so I tried to implement two different ways; one with library and another without. So cache with library is actually the same as making our own dictionary? So does it mean by cache it means we make a dictionary which act as look-up table?

Comment: One more thing, I dont understand, if I were to put the time.sleep(5) at outside the function then I wouldnt able to check the performance. Because I wanted it to cache first and then sleep for 5 seconds before proceed again

Answer (score 1):

You can always play with the code dude,

Your first example is poor to understand the cache mechanism, you are making

Your cache element is going to be formed again & again, as *n = new()* is re-initializing itself. Loosing all the ***cache***.
That is why it’s taking too long. Make it like,

```
 n = new()
 for i in range(0,20):
    print(n.get_candy_price(2))
    print(n.get_candy_price(3))
```

Another thing,

```
    # let's use a sleep to simulate the time your function spends trying to connect to
    # the web service, 5 seconds will be enough.
    time.sleep(5)
```

You want to cache, Right? Then why this web call is getting called every time.
This should always be called only when the answer is not in cache already,
I am redefining your **get_candy_price** function,

```
def get_candy_price(self, candy_id):
    # for observing the results
    print (self.cache, candy_id)
    if candy_id % 2 not in self.cache:

        # as this wasn't already in cache
        # let's use a sleep to simulate the time your function spends trying to connect to
        # the web service, 1 seconds will be enough.
        time.sleep(5)
        if candy_id % 2 == 0:
            self.cache[candy_id % 2] = 1.5
        else:
            self.cache[candy_id % 2] = 1
    else:
        # as we already have cached it
        return self.cache[candy_id % 2]
    return (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%c"), self.cache[candy_id % 2])
```

In second example, play with ttl parameter

```
 cache = TTLCache(maxsize=100, ttl=5)
```

Observe, it’s not going that fast now is it?
It’s because you ttl(Time to live) parameter is caching the result for a certain amount of time. Google it for more!

Answer (score 0):

Your first example `sleep` for 5 seconds no matter it has cache or not, put that line into the `if`, like

```
    if candy_id % 2 not in self.cache:
        time.sleep(5)
        if candy_id % 2 == 0:
            self.cache[candy_id % 2] = 1.5
        else:
            self.cache[candy_id % 2] = 1
```

Also the second example is caching the return-current-time. Therefore, the time part cannot be trusted.

Comment: I tried to alter the codes according to your suggestion but unfortunately, the first one is still slower than the second even without comparing the time, the running is way too slow.

Comment: Did you removed the `sleep` before `if`? @Beginner

Comment: Yes, and instead, I transfer the "time.sleep(5)
" to between for i in range(0,20) and get_candy_price function. It works faster but not sure whether is that the function of timer. My point is to understand the cache in python and so I tried to implement two different ways; one with library and another without. So cache with library is actually the same as making our own dictionary? So does it mean by cache it means we make a dictionary which act as look-up table?

Comment: Oh I got it. You are creating a new object every iteration, put the `n = new()` before `for`. @Beginner

Comment: May I know whether what is the use of the second part for cache? I dont understand it fully, does it work the same as making dictionary and then use as look-up table?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by second part, but yes, cache is more or less equivalent to lookup-table (even when you are talking about CPU cache). @Beginner

Comment: I see, the second part I mean was my "second" example. Haha. Thank you. So I will remember it as a look-up table. thank you so much

Comment: There is one thing I dont understand, since both are using dictionary as a look up table, then the speed should be somewhere near but even after I changed according to your suggestions and push the n = new() above for. The time is still slow. Any idea?

Comment: I didn't find the that big time difference? First one uses `2 s ± 317 µs`, second one uses `2 s ± 346 µs`. I changed 5 second to 1 in order to save time. @Beginner